# SQL to show "AT LEAST 6 riders from same country"

Tags: sql, oracle

My Database Schema 
**BOLD** means **PRIMARY KEY** , *ITALIC* means *FOREIGN KEY*

Countries (Name, **Country_ID**)
Teams (**team_id**, name, c*ountry_id*, description)
Riders (**rider_id**, name, *team_id,* year_born, *country_id*)

I have to provide sql query for the following

find the teams that contain at least 6 riders from the same country as the country that the team is from.

My Answer is as follow:

```
SELECT name
FROM TEAMS
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RIDERS WHERE RIDERS.country_id=TEAMS.country_id AND RIDERS.COUNT>=6);
```

i am not sure how to do "At least 6 riders from same country", could anyone help?

thanks in advance

Comment: any one able to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` the tables on required columns and then,
`GROUP BY team_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=6`

If a `COUNTRY` could have multiple teams, then include country also in the `GROUP BY` clause. This will give you the teams and countries, just select the required rows based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
SELECT
NAME
FROM
TEAMS JOIN RIDERS ON TEAMS.TEAM_ID = RIDERS.TEAM_ID
AND TEAMS.COUNTRY_ID = RIDERS.COUNTRY_ID
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(RIDER_ID)>=6
```